# How do I create inline border style in views table for views data export word output?

Tags: views

I am using [views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module to generate word output. I am able to get word document but views table out is coming without border. How to put border in word output ?

Answer (score 1):

I have created views template and saved in theme folder. then used styles in template itself like below:

```
      <th style="border:1px solid #000000; border-collapse:collapse; padding:5px; min-width:80px" <?php if ($header_classes[$field]) { print 'class="'. $header_classes[$field] . '" '; } ?>>
        <?php print $label; ?>
```

Useful link: http://www.wdtutorials.com/drupal-7/drupal-7-how-to-create-custom-template-view#.VWsGAlJp0-Y